# SAPUI5: How do you update a Label in a View from a json model?

Tags: sapui5

Hi I need help with updating my Label in a view with new values from a json model everytime a button is clicked. How do you do this in SAPUI5?

You can see there is a question text and answer text coming from questionnaire model  I would like to update from data[0].question.text to data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKDFJ.png).question.text which is displayed in my Toolbar text. How to achieve this in SAPUI5?

I have used tool toolbar header for question text and different labels for options? Is this right way? Will I able to update the toolbar header text?

Please find the below code:

**App.view.xml**

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
displayBlock="true" controllerName="opensap.onlinequestionnaire.controller.App" height="100%">
<Page title="Online Questionnaire" class="sapUiContentPadding" id="myPage">
    <headerContent>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://action" tooltip="Share"/>
    </headerContent>
    <subHeader/>
    <content>
        <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
            <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormToolbar" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout">
                <f:toolbar>
                    <Toolbar id="TB1">
                        <Title text="Question 1" level="H4" titleStyle="H4"/>
                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://drop-down-list"/>
                    </Toolbar>
                </f:toolbar>
                <f:content>
                    <Toolbar design="Solid">
                        <Title text="{questionnaire>/data/0/question/text}" level="H5" titleStyle="H5" textAlign="Center" id="questionText"/>
                    </Toolbar>
                    <VBox id="multipleChoiceHolder">
                        <HBox id="answerRow1">
                            <HBox width="700px" backgroundDesign="Solid" alignItems="Center" id="mCHorHolder1"><CheckBox id="checkBox1"/><Label text="Dogs" id="multipleChoice1"/></HBox>
                            <HBox width="700px" backgroundDesign="Solid" alignItems="Center" id="mCHorHolder2"><CheckBox id="checkBox2"/><Label text="Cats" id="multipleChoice2"/></HBox>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox id="answerRow2">
                            <HBox width="700px" backgroundDesign="Solid" alignItems="Center" id="mCHorHolder3"><CheckBox id="checkBox3"/><Label text="Rabbits" id="multipleChoice3"/></HBox>
                            <HBox width="700px" backgroundDesign="Solid" alignItems="Center" id="mCHorHolder4"><CheckBox id="checkBox4"/><Label text="Hamsters" id="multipleChoice4"/></HBox>
                        </HBox>
                    </VBox> </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>
        </VBox>
    </content>
    <footer>
        <Toolbar id="toolBar">
            <Button text="Previous" type="Emphasized" width="300px" press="goToPrevious" icon="sap-icon://navigation-left-arrow" id="previousButton"/>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <Button text="Next" type="Emphasized" width="300px" press="goToNext" icon="sap-icon://navigation-right-arrow" iconFirst="false"
                id="nextButton"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </footer>
</Page>
```

**questionnaire.json**

```
{ data: [{
    "question": "Which pet do you like from the following?",
    "answers": ["Cats", "Rabbits", "Dogs", "Hamsters"],
    "correct": 1
}, {
    "question": "Which pet do you prefer from the following?",
    "answers": ["Cats", "Dogs"],
    "correct": 1
}, {
    "question": "What food brand does your pet eat?",
    "answers": ["Pedigree", "Catfood", "Rabbitfood", "HamstersFood"],

    "correct": 1
}]
}
```

**App.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller){


Controller.extend("opensap.onlinequestionnaire.controller.App", {
    goToPrevious:function(){
        alert("Previous Question");
    },
    goToNext:function(){
        alert("Next Question");
    }
});

});
```

**My FrontEnd looks like this:** [My Frontend looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKDFJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you either store the current index or create a seperate model for your currently selected question. E.g.

```
this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
    index: false,
    question: {}
}), 'currentQuestion');
```

you can define a method to init and / or get the next element

```
initOrSetNext: function() {
  var oCurrentQuestionModel = this.getView().getModel('currentQuestion');
  var oQuestionModel = this.getView().getModel('questionnaire');
  var iCurrentIndex = oCurrentQuestionModel.getProperty('/index');

  // if run first time set to 0 - else increase by one
  iCurrentIndex = iCurrentIndex ? ++iCurrentIndex : 0;

  var oCurrent = {
     index : iCurrentIndex,
     question: oQuestionModel.getProperty('/data/' + iCurrentIndex);
  }
  oCurrentQuestionModel.setProperty('/', oCurrent);
}
```

Answer updated (above) to show incease.

What is missing: check that the next index exists before loading it

Comment: Thank you I like the approach of the new model for the current question. How do I increase the index by  one and assign it to the questionnaire model is the question  because I know how to do this in normal javascript just a for loop  and you store the div's id of current question in a variable and then increment it later. But I don't know to do it in SAPUI5.

Also can I create this separate model by making .json file in model folder or do I need to create it in the init method in a controller?

Comment: Whatever you prefer - I'd say the init method is the best place here. I'll update the answer to show how to inrease it.

Comment: Thank you. I joined SAP as an intern and my task is to develop a web application to display a questionnaire. I have not worked on SAP before so it is difficult understanding it.

Comment: I understand it's a hard start into this topic. I suggest you try the open sap courses for sap ui 5 . They are really helpful!

Comment: I tried your solution  but whenever i am trying to getProperty of oQuestionModel it throws an error in console "cannot read property of undefined"

How do I get the property of my questionnaire model - question in my controller ? 

My questionnaire model is as below:

{
 "data": [{
  "question": "Which pet do you like from the following?",
  "answers": ["Cats", "Rabbits", "Dogs", "Hamsters"],
  "correct": 1
 }, ]
}

Comment: the error basically means that you did not initialize your model correctly.

Comment: the questionnaire.json is a named model I defined it in the manifest.json. Do i still need to initialize it? and how do you do it then?

Comment: oh sorry - actually no. Currently I can't see the mistake sorry

Comment: oh okay. Thank you @Frank Provost for all the help.

Comment: I solved this one. According to what I think to get model which is defined in the manifest I had to use the getOwnerComponent().getModel() method.
One more thing that I was doing wrong was trying to get the property of the model in the init() before the model was loaded so I used getProperty in new method and got the result. Thank you for helping all the way long.